# Bitbucket WebHooks Jenkins Pipeline Trigger Payload

Tags: git, jenkins, bitbucket, jenkins-pipeline

We have a pipeline in Jenkins that we want to trigger upon creating\updating pull requests on a particular repository.

There will be multiple branches for the repo such as feature\bugfix etc, so we configured the webhook trigger such that if a pull request is created or updated, the webhook triggers the pipeline from Bitbucket which includes the **Payload** data which in-turn includes the source and target branches that we need in the pipeline

Now we want somehow that JSON payload data included in the Bitbucket's webhook to be parse into the pipeline and get the source and target branches in the pipeline. My question is what is way to get this job done?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: i have done something similar. Basically you need to create a proxy server, i used this one https://github.com/akhy/jenkins-bitbucket-webhook-proxy . I started the proxy server using this code, and changed bitbucket webhook to send requests to that proxy server. Then I modified `app.py` to get the *Payload* and extract what I want.  
Finally I make call to Jenkins Job and pass the JSON as Build input parameter

Comment: That's fine but there is a line confusing saying **Note: Currently the proxy can only handle repository push trigger.** What if I want to do the same with pull requests created\merge\update? Where should I make the change in the proxy?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the [Generic Webhook Trigger Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Generic+Webhook+Trigger+Plugin) can resolve variables from the payload.